# Why is $\Bigl\{ \frac{a}{a-1} \mid a \ne 1, a \in \mathbb{F}_p \Bigr\} = \Bigl\{ b \mid b \ne -1, b \in \mathbb{F}_p \Bigr\}$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime. Why is

$$\Bigl\{ \frac{a}{a-1} \mid a \ne 1,  a \in \mathbb{F}_p \Bigr\} = \Bigl\{ b \mid b \ne -1, b \in \mathbb{F}_p \Bigr\} \quad ?$$

I have checked this identity for samll $p$ by hand, but I do not see how to prove it. I know the similar lemma from group theory that, given a group $(G,\cdot)$ with $h \in G$ fixed,

$$\{gh \mid g \in G \} = \{g \mid g \in G \}.$$

, but I do not see if (or how) this can be realted to my question.

Comment: Hint: $a/(a-1)=1+1/(a-1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I understand why your identity is true, but I do not get how this should help me here.

Comment: What is the range (i.e. possible values) of $1/x$? What is the range of $1/(a-1)$? Now what is the range of $1+1/(a-1)$?

Comment: The range for $1/x$ is $1,\ldots,p-1$, the same holds true for $1/(a-1)$. The range of $1+1/(a-1)$ is $0,2,3,\ldots,p-1$.

Comment: So, $\{a/(a-1) | a \ne 1\}  = \{ b | b \ne 1\}$.

Comment: But I wanted $\{ b \mid b \ne -1, b \in \mathbb{F}_p  \}$

Comment: So you can't get what you want. That's simple. It's also pointed out in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With
$$A = \left\{ \frac{a}{a-1} \mid a \ne 1,  a \in \Bbb F_p \right\}$$
and
$$B=\Bbb F_p\setminus\{-1\}$$
your claim $A=B$ implies $-1\notin A$. There is however a solution to
$$\frac a{a-1}=-1\tag1$$
Multiply (1) by $a-1$ assuming $a\neq1$ yields
$$a=1-a\tag2$$
and $2a=1$ has in characteristic not equal to 2 the solution
$$a=\frac12=\frac{p+1}2 \tag3$$
You can plug (3) back into (1), and as $1\neq a=1/2\neq0$ resp. $1/a=2$:
$$\frac{a}{a-1}
\stackrel{a\neq0}= \frac1{1-1/a}
\stackrel{(3)}= \frac1{1-2} = -1
$$
Thus your conjecture is false.  And it's still false over $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ provided $p\neq2$.